# Thumbnail floating on screen after deletion from desktop

Tags: high-sierra, desktop

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) running High Sierra 10.13.3.

Recently when I have dragged and deleted image files from my desktop there has been a thumbnail of one of the pictures deleted left floating on the screen, it seems to be on a layer above anything else and the only way I can get rid of it is restarting my laptop.

Anyone else experienced this/found a fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

⌥-right-click on Finder in the Dock and choose Relaunch.

This is an occasional bug in Finder that's been around for years. In my experience it happens fairly randomly when dragging files or folders around. If you have reproducible steps to recreate the problem, you should [file a bug report](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)!